# How to get start and end date with momentjs?

Tags: fullcalendar, momentjs

I get the start date of my calendar like this:

```
var date_start = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').start
```

with `.toDate()` I can see this result in chrome console:

> Mon Nov 09 2015 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (ora solare Europa occidentale)

I need to display this result:

> Mon Nov 09 2015 00:00:00

I also want get the end of the day, should be this:

> Tue Nov 10 2015 00:00:00

How I can achieve this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toDate` gives you back a JavaScript `Date` object.  Any output string is therefore based on the specific implementation of `Date.toString`.  If you want specific output, you should instead format using moment's [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) function.

```
date_start.format("ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss")
```

However, this will return 01:00 and you asked for 00:00.  It's not clear if you are asking for the local start-of-day, or if you're asking for the equivalent UTC value.

If you wanted the local start of the day:

```
date_start.clone().startOf('day').format("ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss")
```

If you wanted the equivalent UTC value:

```
date_start.clone().utc().format("ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss")
```

Cloning is important, as moment objects are *mutable*.  If you don't clone, then you'll be manipulating the original moment, which could have unintended side effects in fullcalendar.  You can use either the `clone` function shown above, or you can wrap it in the moment function, as in `moment(date_start)...`  Both do the same thing.

For the ending value, looks like you want the start of the next day, so do this:

```
date_start.clone().startOf('day').add(1, 'day').format("ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss")
```

Or:

```
date_start.clone().utc().add(1, 'day').format("ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss")
```

Again, pick the one that corresponds to your usage scenario.

FYI - you seem to be asking for UTC, but in the vast majority of cases, local time is more relevant when displaying a calendar such as fullcalendar to a user.

Comment: Just a thing: .clone() return is not a function why?

Comment: Clone returns a new moment object.  Why would you expect it to return a function?

Comment: One problem: pastebin.com/Qm5Wyzsm How you can see return +0100 it's possible set +0000 or delete gmt?

Comment: If you're asking how to format the string to contain the offset, use `ZZ` (please [read the docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)).  In total, the output format can be `'ddd, D MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT] ZZ'`.  Also, in your pastebin, you have an aweful lot of unnecessary code.  Don't try to format a string just to parse it again, and in most cases you can avoid the `Date` object completely.

Comment: could you post an update in your answer? I'm not very good with the date, thanks for the support.